# Not All Reports are getting printed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, reportviewer

I am facing this fairly strange issue, i have a two sections with buttons:
1) print one item 
2) print all items

When a button is clicked from the print one item section, it takes some parameters and process a report for that one particular item

when i try the same with no parameters and do a select * one would think that it would return all the items but it is only returning a single one.

**Print One Item**

Query Used to populate the dataset which is then used as a source for the report

```
SELECT  [Unit UPC Base Item], [Production Line], 
        [Production Line Description], [Preset Number], 
        [Weight Factor], Piece, [Pcs Per Unit], 
        [Upper Limit Unit], [Upper Limit Factor], [Label Wt (g)], 
        [Tare Wt (g)], [Constant Tare Wt (g)], 
        [Pkg Length (mm)], [Film Product Code], 
        [Film Width (mm)], [Forming Tube (mm)], 
        [Type of Jaws], [Last Updated], 
        [Item Description], [MAV (g)], [PieceWeight(g)], UL1, UL2, 
        UL3,[UpperLimit(g)], [LowerLimit(g)],
        [Label Wt (g)] + [Tare Wt (g)] AS [Target Wt (g)]
FROM    [Net Weight Master Data Report]
WHERE   ([Unit UPC Base Item] = @upc) AND ([Production Line Description] = @prod)
```

Final Report Generated:

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVMt2.png)

**The Above Looks Good**

**Print All Item**

Query Used to populate the dataset which is then used as a source for the report

```
SELECT [Unit UPC Base Item], [Production Line], 
       [Production Line Description], [Preset Number], 
       [Weight Factor], Piece, [Pcs Per Unit], [Upper Limit Unit], 
       [Upper Limit Factor], [Label Wt (g)], [Tare Wt (g)], 
       [Constant Tare Wt (g)], [Pkg Length (mm)], [Film Product Code], 
       [Film Width (mm)], [Forming Tube (mm)], [Type of Jaws], 
       [Last Updated], [Item Description], [MAV (g)], [PieceWeight(g)], 
       UL1, UL2, UL3, [UpperLimit(g)], [LowerLimit(g)], 
       [Repair Min Wt (g)]
FROM   [Net Weight Master Data Report]
ORDER BY [Unit UPC Base Item]
```

Final Report Generated

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWHr.png)

**As you can see the highlighted sections from the above pic 1) it chooses the last record 2) it only displays the last record there are a total of 2327 records hence 2327 reports needs to be created**

I am not able to see what is wrong with my query or is it an error on the reporting side.

**ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!!!**

**Edit**

Code used to display the report on to the report viewer

```
namespace CorsicanaNetWeightProgram
{
    public partial class PrintAllBag : Form
    {


        public PrintAllBag()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PrintAllBag_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'corsicanaNetWeightDataSet11.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1TableAdapter.Fill(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet11.Net_Weight_Master_Data_Report1);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); 
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reportViewer1.PrintDialog();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: besides the reporting in regards to the SQL..what are you using to Display the Reports.. is this ReportViewer, ASP.NET, WinForms, etc.. is there any C# Code involved in this..? if so please show the code related to this issue..

Comment: @MethodMan i am using reportviewer 2008 on WinForm application, i created a data set, then from the report viewer i clicked design new report and created the report, then choose the selection from the report viewer and chose the newly generated report and that generated some code, i posted that code under the edit section in the question above hope that helps

Comment: @MethodMan did you get a chance to look at the edited question, any help would be seriously appreciated, still stuck on this issue

Comment: your code does me no good I think you need to actually open up the ReportViewer and look at the fields that are being mapped / defined and make sure that there is not a typo in and of the field / data field names..

Comment: @MethodMan i opened up my report designer and look at all the fields they are mapped correctly, i then did a preview on my data set and im getting the respected result but it is not getting display on my report. any other suggestions plz??

Comment: if you Don't have this in the Page Directive add it  `EnableEventValidation="fase" and for the report control set AsyncRendering = false;`

Comment: @MethodMan where exactly can i find the page directive your talking about?? plz help as i have never used such thing before.

Comment: the .aspx page at the top if you are doing this in a web form.

Comment: @MethodMan see that is why i couldn't find it, my application is a Windows Form Application, so what would be an alternative for an windows forms application?

Comment: Just looks to me even though you are calling the `.Fill()` Method, that you are not explicitly assigning the `DataSource` of the report viewer.. I could be wrong but take a look at how `MSDN documentation example` does it linked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089.aspx